# Import .dbf file into Oracle database wrong date imported

Tags: c#, oracle, import, dbf

I'm using a C# program to import a .dbf file into an Oracle database. Everything works fine, but the date format is imported wrong. Ex: 01.01.1420 instead of 01.01.2014. So the century and year are swapped. I am using `OracleBulkCopy`, with `OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(datatable)` function.

When I import in local database, everything works fine.

I've done some research about this bug, but i haven't found any solutions. Has anyone meet this problem, and have any solution?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Could you quote us the value of  `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` environment variables from both the working and non-working oracle hosts?

Comment: i have on both "dd-mon-rr" . is any method where i can change this settings in database?